# How to deal with "less than" symbol in soap message?

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

When i test soap message using soapUI,i send a filter to my web service ,like this form:

```
     <p_filter xsi:type="soap:filter" xmlns:soap="http://mfisoft.ru/voip/service/soap">
        <!--You may enter the following 5 items in any order-->
        <type xsi:type="xsd:string">cond</type>
        <column xsi:type="xsd:string">total_current_balance</column>
        <operator xsi:type="xsd:string">=</operator>         **<!-- pls notice this line-->**
        <value xsi:type="xsd:string">0.0</value>
     </p_filter>
```

in order to find record where total_current_balance=0,
it works fine,but when i change ths symbol from "=" to "<",that is

```
      <operator xsi:type="xsd:string"><</operator>
```

the web service return an error,i guess it may mis parse the statement,but i don't know how to write symbol "<" correctly,can anyone help me? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CDATA section to avoid content being parsed by the parser.

For example.

```
<operator xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[<]]></operator>
```

Comment: <operator xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[<]]></operator>   <!--ok-->

Answer (score 1):

Example
Work_Date <= 20131230T000000Z

instead of < replace it with &lt; or 
instead of > replace it with &gt; does the job

Thanks EFrank

Comment: might be better to use the question to produce your example

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the < as &lt ;

```
 <operator xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;</operator>
```

See also here: [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)